# mouseleave only when first animation load jquery

Tags: jquery

Im having problems with jquery.

I have this code and works fine.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#botonbox" ).click(function() {
        $( ".middle-content-left" ).css( "height", "700" );
        $( "#normalboxid" ).animate({height:'700px'},1000 );
        $( "#botonbox" ).css( "display", "none" );
    });
});
</script>
```

And i want only when this animation end, if cursor mouseleave .middle-content-back, back to first heights (.middle-content-left to height:310px and #normalboxdiv to height:132px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.click` method doesn't have a callback; it only has a handler parameter. In other words, the second `function() { }` block is a syntax error.

Instead, if you want the second portion to activate once `#normalboxid` is done animating, create a global variable, and set it to true when the element is clicked. Then, inside the mouse leave handler, check if the previous variable is true or false:

```
<script>
var botonboxClicked = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#botonbox" ).click(function() {
        $( ".middle-content-left" ).css( "height", "700" );
        $( "#normalboxid" ).animate({height:'700px'}, 1000, function() {
            botonboxClicked = true;
        });
        $( "#botonbox" ).css( "display", "none" );
    });
    $( ".middle-content-left" ).mouseleave(function() {
        if (botonboxClicked) {
            $( ".middle-content-left" ).animate({height:'310px'},1000 );
            $( "#normalboxid" ).animate({height:'132px'},1000 );
            $( "#botonbox" ).css( "display", "block" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/click/ and http://api.jquery.com/animate/.

Comment: thanks for explanation @apparatix but this script don't work. my script work if only put the first part but this nothing.
And thanks everyone for negative votes and support a noob guest.

Comment: @vektor Sorry I misread your code (try to indent your code :p) I updated my answer.

Comment: don't worry, i tried improve my code and explanation xD but your code works perfectly!!! Only one question. is possible put #botonbox css when animation finish?

Comment: The third parameter for `.animate()` is the callback function, which activates when the animation is complete. If you want to change the CSS when the animation is complete, move that line inside the callback function.

Comment: thanks!! that was easy after your explanation.

Comment: your code works fine, but .middle-content-left dont go to height:700px if the cursor mouseleave itself. some idea?

Comment: is not necesary. i have a href="#" link and adding  onClick="return false;" don't scroll up.